# How to create a Log file in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

How can i create zend log.I need to create on manual file in application folder and write response data in that file with full description.

Comment: Is this for ZF1 or ZF2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of each framework:

In ZendFramework 1.12 you can do the following:

```
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('/path/to/logfile');
$logger = new Zend_Log($writer);

$logger->info('Informational message');
```

[Documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.log.writers.html)

In ZendFramework 2 you can do the following:

```
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();

//log to file
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(getcwd() . '/path/to/logfile');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Information message');
```

[Documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.log.overview.html)